# Parallel operations on Kotlin collections?

Tags: parallel-processing, kotlin

In Scala, one can easily do a parallel map, forEach, etc, with:

```
collection.par.map(..)
```

Is there an equivalent in Kotlin?

Comment: Some of the fastest parallel collections around are from GS-Collections:  https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections ... which you can use from Kotlin (as any Java collection framework can be used)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The Kotlin standard library has no support for parallel operations. However, since Kotlin uses the standard Java collection classes, you can use the Java 8 stream API to perform parallel operations on Kotlin collections as well.

e.g.

```
myCollection.parallelStream()
        .map { ... }
        .filter { ... }
```

Comment: how can one use Java 8 stream API in Kotlin?

Comment: @LordScone The same way as you'd do it in Java. E.g.: `myCollection.parallelStream().map { ... }. filter { ... }`

Comment: just for information, parallelStream is only advised in case of long lists, for smaller lists, it will be an overhead to run the 2 jobs in different threads as in java world. Stick to coroutines as far as possible

Comment: parallelStream is Java, not kotlin, that's why it requires Java 8

Comment: @MozenRath what if we have lists not long, but items in list may take a long time to finish. Would you advise parallelStream ?

Answer (score 49):

As of Kotlin 1.1, parallel operations can also be expressed quite elegantly in terms of [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html). Here is a custom `pmap` helper function for lists:

```
fun <A, B>List<A>.pmap(f: suspend (A) -> B): List<B> = runBlocking {
    map { async(Dispatchers.Default) { f(it) } }.map { it.await() }
}
```

Comment: With Kotlin 1.3 out, is this still the best answer?  I noticed @OlivierTerrien's Stream answer below, but I'd prefer to stick with Kotlin Sequences and Iterables.

Comment: @BenjaminH Thanks; I have marked yole's answer as accepted, as it also refers to the stream API and posted before OlivierTerrien's answer.

Comment: Quite elegantly? On the contrary, the code is pretty hard to read I would say.

Comment: @DzmitryLazerka I think I see where you're coming from, but this exact code isn't the elegant bit.  The use of this code is what's elegant.  If the above method is placed somewhere, it can be used with just `foo.pmap { v -> ...  }`.  I think that's fairly elegant.

Comment: Currently 'CommonPool' cannot be accessed - it is internal in 'kotlinx.coroutines'!

Comment: This is in fact the best performing solution i think. It does not have any overheads like a parallelStream. Although would have loved to see a helper method from kotlin that could cater to it.

Comment: @Strinder You can use Dispatchers.Default instead of CommonPool, see
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/commonpool-default-for-coroutines/11965/3 and
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/pull/633

Comment: `.map { it.await() }` can now be replaced with `.awaitAll()`.

Answer (score 30):

You can use this extension method:

```
suspend fun <A, B> Iterable<A>.pmap(f: suspend (A) -> B): List<B> = coroutineScope {
    map { async { f(it) } }.awaitAll()
}
```

See [Parallel Map in Kotlin](https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/05/04/parallel-map-in-kotlin/) for more info

Answer (score 17):

There is no official support in Kotlin's stdlib yet, but you could define an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html)  to mimic `par.map`:

```
fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.pmap(
          numThreads: Int = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 2, 
          exec: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads),
          transform: (T) -> R): List<R> {

    // default size is just an inlined version of kotlin.collections.collectionSizeOrDefault
    val defaultSize = if (this is Collection<*>) this.size else 10
    val destination = Collections.synchronizedList(ArrayList<R>(defaultSize))

    for (item in this) {
        exec.submit { destination.add(transform(item)) }
    }

    exec.shutdown()
    exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)

    return ArrayList<R>(destination)
}
```

([github source](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kutils/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/kutils/ParCollections.kt))

Here's a simple usage example

```
val result = listOf("foo", "bar").pmap { it+"!" }.filter { it.contains("bar") }
```

If needed it allows to tweak threading by providing the number of threads or even a specific `java.util.concurrent.Executor`. E.g.

```
listOf("foo", "bar").pmap(4, transform = { it + "!" })
```

Please note, that this approach just allows to parallelize the `map` operation and does not affect any downstream bits. E.g. the `filter` in the first example would run single-threaded. However, in many cases just the data transformation (ie. `map`) requires parallelization. Furthermore, it would be straightforward to extend the approach from above to other elements of Kotlin collection API.

Comment: I don't see how "destination.add(transform(item))" is thread safe. What's to keep two threads from calling "destination.add" at the same time, thus breaking stuff since ArrayList.add() is not a thread safe operation?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Quite [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715983/concurrent-threads-adding-to-arraylist-at-same-time-what-happens) people think that when just adding elements it should be fine without synchronization. However, I've changed it to use a synchronized list to improve thread-safety.

Comment: The order in destination may not be the same as in the original list

Comment: I think many parallel collection implementations (like in [scala](http://beust.com/weblog/2011/08/15/scalas-parallel-collections/)) do not care about preserving order. Though, by changing the for-each loop above to an indexed loop along with downstream resorting, order could be preserved easily.

Comment: I'm interested in a version that returns a `Sequence<R>` (or `Flow<R>`). Unfortunately I can't simply have the whole code execute in an `= execute{` block and call `yield` instead of `destination.add` because `yield` can only execute in the original block, so within `exec.submit { }` is not an option. (Order need not be preserved.)

Comment: I suspect this was an amazing answer in 2016 when it was provided, but now that Structured Concurrency exists in Kotlin we should instead be using `coroutineScope` with `async { ... }` as indicated in @Sharon 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58735169/1672027)

Answer (score 13):

From 1.2 version, kotlin added a [stream feature](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.streams/index.html) which is compliant with JRE8

So, iterating over a list asynchronously could be done like bellow:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val c = listOf("toto", "tata", "tutu")
  c.parallelStream().forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Comment: I am not following kotlin very closely; isn't this the same as Yole's answer?I appreciate that your answer has sample code. Maybe we can edit Yole's answer to add the sample code.

Comment: @HRJ, not exactly. Yole said Kotlin had no support for stream which is true until version 1.2. Since this version, Kotlin provides a way to stream collections as Java8 does.

Comment: Yole said "Kotlin has no support for parallel operations". Please check again.

Comment: Yes you are right. Too quickly written. Parallel operations not stream.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that as this requires JRE8 it is only available on Android 24 and above.

Comment: Nothing in this answer is Kotlin per se, it is calling Java standard library. Which is not bad, just not Kotlin specific.

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin wants to be idiomatic but not too much synthetic to be hard to understand at a first glance.

Parallel computation trough Coroutines is no exception. They want it to be easy but not implicit with some pre-built method, allowing to branch the computation when needed.

In your case:

```
collection.map { 
        async{ produceWith(it) } 
    }
    .forEach { 
        consume(it.await()) 
    }
```

Notice that to call `async` and `await` you need to be inside a so called `Context`, you cannot make suspending calls or launching a coroutine from a non-coroutine context. To enter one you can either:

- `runBlocking { /* your code here */ }`: it will suspend the current thread until the lambda returns.
- `GlobalScope.launch { }`: it will execute the lambda in parallel; if your `main` finishes executing while your coroutines have not bad things will happen, in that case better use `runBlocking`.

Hope it may helps :)

Comment: While I appreciate Kotlin not wanting to be opaque, surely this is a common enough requirement to warrant an extension method? forEachParallel or something similar

Comment: Do not use `GlobalScope`.

Answer (score 4):

At the present moment no. The official Kotlin comparison to Scala mentions:

> Things that may be added to Kotlin later:
>
> - Parallel collections

Answer (score 4):

This solution assumes that your project is using coroutines:

```
implementation( "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2")
```

The functions called `parallelTransform` don't retain the order of elements and return a `Flow<R>`, while the function `parallelMap` retains the order and returns a `List<R>`.

Create a threadpool for multiple invocations:

```
val numberOfCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
val executorDispatcher: ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher =
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfCores ).asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

use that dispatcher (and call `close()` when it's no longer needed):

```
inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.parallelTransform(
    dispatcher: ExecutorDispatcher,
    crossinline transform: (T) -> R
): Flow<R> = channelFlow {

    val items: Iterable<T> = this@parallelTransform
    val channelFlowScope: ProducerScope<R> = this@channelFlow

    launch(dispatcher) {
        items.forEach {item ->
            launch {
                channelFlowScope.send(transform(item))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If threadpool reuse is of no concern (threadpools aren't cheap), you can use this version:

```
inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.parallelTransform(
    numberOfThreads: Int,
    crossinline transform: (T) -> R
): Flow<R> = channelFlow {

    val items: Iterable<T> = this@parallelTransform
    val channelFlowScope: ProducerScope<R> = this@channelFlow

    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads).asCoroutineDispatcher().use { dispatcher ->
        launch( dispatcher ) {
            items.forEach { item ->
                launch {
                    channelFlowScope.send(transform(item))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you need a version that retains the order of elements:

```
inline fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.parallelMap(
    dispatcher: ExecutorDispatcher,
    crossinline transform: (T) -> R
): List<R> = runBlocking {

    val items: Iterable<T> = this@parallelMap
    val result = ConcurrentSkipListMap<Int, R>()

    launch(dispatcher) {
        items.withIndex().forEach {(index, item) ->
            launch {
                result[index] = transform(item)
            }
        }
    }

    // ConcurrentSkipListMap is a SortedMap
    // so the values will be in the right order
    result.values.toList()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this:

implementation 'com.github.cvb941:kotlin-parallel-operations:1.3'

details:

https://github.com/cvb941/kotlin-parallel-operations

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a couple of extension functions:

1. The `suspend` extension function on `Iterable<T>` type, which does a parallel processing of items and returns some result of processing each item. By default it uses `Dispatchers.IO` dispatcher to offload blocking tasks to a shared pool of threads. Must be called from a coroutine (including a coroutine with `Dispatchers.Main` dispatcher) or another `suspend` function.

   ```
   suspend fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.processInParallel(
       dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
       processBlock: suspend (v: T) -> R,
   ): List<R> = coroutineScope { // or supervisorScope
       map {
           async(dispatcher) { processBlock(it) }
       }.awaitAll()
   }
   ```

   Example of calling from a coroutine:

   ```
   val collection = listOf("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

   someCoroutineScope.launch {
       val results = collection.processInParallel {
           process(it)
       }
       // use processing results
   }
   ```

where `someCoroutineScope` is an instance of [`CoroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/).

2. Launch and forget extension function on `CoroutineScope`, which doesn't return any result. It also uses `Dispatchers.IO` dispatcher by default. Can be called using `CoroutineScope` or from another coroutine.

   ```
   fun <T> CoroutineScope.processInParallelAndForget(
       iterable: Iterable<T>,
       dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
       processBlock: suspend (v: T) -> Unit
   ) = iterable.forEach {
       launch(dispatcher) { processBlock(it) }
   }
   ```

   Example of calling:

   ```
   someoroutineScope.processInParallelAndForget(collection) {
       process(it)
   }

   // OR from another coroutine:

   someCoroutineScope.launch {
       processInParallelAndForget(collection) {
           process(it)
       }
   }
   ```

2a. Launch and forget extension function on `Iterable<T>`. It's almost the same as previous, but the extension type is different. `CoroutineScope` must be passed as argument to the function.

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.processInParallelAndForget(
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
    processBlock: suspend (v: T) -> Unit
) = forEach {
    scope.launch(dispatcher) { processBlock(it) }
}
```

Calling:

```
collection.processInParallelAndForget(someCoroutineScope) {
    process(it)
}

// OR from another coroutine:

someScope.launch {
    collection.processInParallelAndForget(this) {
        process(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mimic the Scala API by using [extension properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-properties) and [inline classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html). Using the coroutine solution from @Sharon answer, you can write it like this

```kotlin
val <A> Iterable<A>.par get() = ParallelizedIterable(this)

@JvmInline
value class ParallelizedIterable<A>(val iter: Iterable<A>) {
    suspend fun <B> map(f: suspend (A) -> B): List<B> = coroutineScope {
        iter.map { async { f(it) } }.awaitAll()
    }
}
```

with this, now your code can change from

```kotlin
anIterable.map { it.value }
```

to

```kotlin
anIterable.par.map { it.value }
```

also you can change the entry point as you like other than using extension properties, e.g.

```kotlin
fun <A> Iterable<A>.parallel() = ParallelizedIterable(this)

anIterable.parallel().map { it.value }
```

You can also use another parallel solution and implement the rest of iterable methods inside `ParallelizedIterable` while still having the same method names for the operations

The drawback is that this implementation can only parallelize one operation after it, to make it so that it parallelize every subsequent operation, you may need to modify `ParallelizedIterable` further so it return its own type instead of returning back to `List<A>`